# how to make navigation buttons next to each other horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my navigation buttons to be next to each other, like in this example: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/RKRbwL

Here is my code:

```
<header id="header">
<img id="header-img" src="https://www.logobee.com/uploads/tesla-logo.png"/>
<nav id="nav-bar">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Features">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Demo">Demo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Pricing">Pricing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>

<section id="Features">
<h3>EXOSKELETON</h3>
<p>Cybertruck is built with an exterior shell made for ultimate durability and passenger protection. Starting with a nearly impenetrable exoskeleton, every component is designed for superior strength and endurance, from Ultra-Hard 30X Cold-Rolled stainless-steel structural skin to Tesla armor glass.</p> 
<h3>ULTRA-HARD 30X COLD-ROLLED STAINLESS STEEL</h3>
<p>If there was something better, we’d use it. Help eliminate dents, damage and long-term corrosion with a smooth monochrome exoskeleton that puts the shell on the outside of the car and provides you and your passengers maximum protection.</p>
<h3>TESLA ARMOR GLASS</h3>
<p>Ultra-strong glass and polymer-layered composite can absorb and redirect impact force for improved performance and damage tolerance.</p>
</section>

<section id="Demo">
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m7atGkba-Z8" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section> 

<section id="Pricing">
<h3>Single-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
<ul>
<li>$39,900</li>
<li>250+ miles of range</li>
<li>0-60 moh in 6.5 seconds</li>
<li>top speed of 110 mph</li>
</ul> 
<h3>Dual-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
<ul>
<li>$49,900</li>
<li>300+ miles of range</li>
<li>0-60 moh in 4.5 seconds</li>
<li>top speed of 120 mph</li>
</ul>
<h3>Tri-Motor Cybertruck</h3>
<ul>
<li>$69,900</li>
<li>500+ miles of range</li>
<li>0-60 moh in 2.9 seconds</li>
<li>top speed of 130 mph</li>
</ul>
</section>

<form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
<input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email"></input>
<input id="submit" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
header {
position: fixed;
left: 480px;
top: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
position: fixed;
left: 200px;
}

#header-img {
height: 80px;
}

header {
display: flex;
}

li {
display: flex;
}
```

How do I do this? thank you!

also, I copy and paste my code from codepen into stack overflow but I have to manually space out my code so it is formatted correctly. How do I make it so I can just copy and paste code and have it automatically formatted? I used the code toolbar but it only makes the first line of code formatted.

Comment: create a js fiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the nav items to be placed horizontally, you should apply `display: flex` property to the parent container, i.e, `ul` in your case.

```
nav ul {
 display: flex;
}
```

My bad, there should be a space between `nav` and `ul`. I've updated my answer. Now it will target only the `nav` elements

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but it didn't work but just simply ul instead of the nav.ul works. But then it also changes the layout of the other ul elements lower in the page. How do I make it only modify the nav items?

Comment: @peterpiper3407. I've updated my answer. Please check

Comment: I tried your updated code but it doesn't work for some reason. Please help

Comment: @peterpiper3407, please remove the `.` Updated the code

Comment: yes it works now thank you

Comment: @peterpiper3407 You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped. :)